# Probability of distributing n elements into k bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We are distributing $n$ distinguishable elements into $k$ distinguishable bins where $n>k>2$.

What is the probability of having all $n$ elements landing in the first two bins?

I tackled this problem with star and bars: there are $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to distribute the n elements into the k bins total.

Then I restrict the bins to be 2, and have $\binom{n+2-1}{2-1}$ or n+1 ways to distribute n elements into 2 bins, and took the quotient.

However, I noticed that star and bars works when the elements are indistinguishable, so this answer must be wrong.

My second attempt was to say there is $k^{n}$ ways to distribute $n$ distinguishable elements into $k$ distinguishable bins, which leads to the final answer of $\frac{k^{2}}{k^{n}} = \frac{1}{k^{n-2}}$.

But I picked some numbers and simulated with the computer and the experimental result is also not close with my calculated result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element lands in one of the first two bins. So there are two choices for each element and that makes it $2^n$ choices for $n$ distinguishable elements. But this also includes arrangements where all the $n$ elements are in either bin $1$ or bin $2$. We should subtract those. We also note there is only one way for all elements to be in a bin.

That gives us $2^n-2$ arrangements out of total $k^n$ unrestricted arrangements ($k$ choices for each element and $k^n$ choices for $n$ elements).

So the probability is $\displaystyle \frac{2^n-2}{k^n}$.